# How to manage CIFS permissions on a mounted drive in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cifs, nas

I have copied over from a cifs mounted volume to another cifs mounted volume a large number of files. The 2 volumes were mounted locally with the following command:

```bsh
# mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password>,domain=<domain> //nas1.domain.com/volume1 /mnt/folder1
# mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password>,domain=<domain> //nas2.domain.com/volume2 /mnt/folder2
```

Very specific permissions were granted to specific Active Directory domain groups on the files. However, when I list the files on the destination, they all belong to `root:root`.

How do I:

- know the name of the group the permissions were originally granted to (i.e. list all the permissions on the parent / volume folder - here volume2)?
- list the permissions that were set while copying?

Preferably, I'd like to avoid having to install a Windows machine just for this...